# Django OperationalError at / (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")

Tags: python, mysql, django

Well, it refuses to work with `root`, but my settings are:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'stroiset74',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'stroiset74',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '*****',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

Interestingly, `manage.py validate` and `manage.py syncdb` still run without errors.

Comment: Are you using some kind of local_settings.py file? Does the database name is the same as your user? Did you grant privileges to stroitet74?

Comment: Thank you Cesar. Yes, username and dbname are equal. local_settings.py has same options. Privileges are granted. I simply don't understand, why django adresses to database on behalf of root?

Comment: Do you have another Django project somewhere whose settings.py is being used instead of the one you're looking at?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, the issue was i had a local_settings.py with database configuration. changed the DB password.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem on MY windows10 by searching the username globally in the project, and I found that both settings.py and views.py contains the username and password.

I only changed the configuration in settings.py, after changing the password in the views.py, the django worked.